# Karate test run several times

Tags: karate

I'm not a native speaker of English, but I want to ask a question at here. and I am a beginner at Karate.

I am testing POST request to server. and I want to send only one time.

but, my log said, it sent 3 time same post request to server when I exec.

I dont know why It happned.

```
Feature: CBtest
Scenario:
    Given url 'http://localhost:8888/api/insert'
    And request {"name" : "fooooo"}
    When method post
    Then status 200
```

Is there any way to send(run,exec) only once?